# if condition in xPath/xQuery

Tags: xml, xpath, if-statement, concatenation

To concatenate results from xpath, i'm using `concat(normalize-space(.), '&#xA;')` (Thanks to [Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev)).

Now i'm wondering how to avoid adding `&#xA;` after the last element... I'm thinking about something like: `concat(normalize-space(.), if(XXXXX) then '&#xA;' else '')` but I couldn't figure out what condition do I have to use.

For example, If I'm using `xpathExpression/concat(normalize-space(.), ',')` and the values requested are (strings) A & B & C & D, the output I'm expecting is `A,B,C,D` instead of `A,B,C,D,`.... so the expression may become: `xpathExpression/concat(normalize-space(.), if(this is the last element D) then '' else ',')`

Comment: Is this purely for indentation purposes?

Comment: Is 'last element' a last fully qualified element in your input xml or just any element that just happend to be the last one being processed?

Comment: @rene: the last element in the list to be processed... I added an example above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in XQuery or in XPath 2.0, you can use the string-join function, for example

```
string-join(//author, ', ')
```

will give you a result like

```
Fleming, Rowling, Pullmann
```

If you are in XPath 1.0, there's no easy equivalent - but it's not clear from your question exactly what the context is.

Comment: I found it a few minutes ago :)  Thanks :)